# Linking image to post URL not pointing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I have this code inserted into one my blocks.

```
<div data-content="FOR GIRLS" class="image">
<img src="path_to_image" 
alt="" />
</div>
<p></p>

<div data-content="FOR BOYS" class="image">
<img src="path_to_image" 
alt="" />
</div>
```

tryed to link the image to post URL, in this way:

```
<div data-content="FOR GIRLS" class="image">
<a href="link_to_post"><img src="path_to_image" 
alt="" /></a>
</div>
<p></p>

<div data-content="FOR BOYS" class="image">
<a href="link_to_post"><img src="path_to_image" 
alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

but when save the changes image still is not linked nowhere..

This is CSS for image class:

```
.image img {
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:95%;
}
.image:after, .image:before {
position:absolute;
opacity:0;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:after {
content:'\A';
width:100%; height:100%;
top:0; left:0;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.image:before {
content: attr(data-content);
width:100%;
color:#fff;
z-index:1;
bottom:0;
padding:0px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:black;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
opacity:1;
}
```

I dont know what is wrong, and why i cant link image in that way. Some tips?

Comment: I see you use wordpress tag here. In what post type you link to your post ? is it single post / page / attachment page ? what is the target link of each image ?

Comment: Need to point to category products URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for html:

```
<div data-content="FOR GIRLS" class="image">
    <a class="wrapped__link" href="link_to_post">&nbsp;</a>
    <img src="path_to_image" alt="" />
</div>
```

and for css:

```
div.image {
    position: relative;
}
.wrapped__link {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: transparent;
}
```